# Running a Web Service

Tags: .net, web, service

I have a web service created in .NET. I thought I had setup everything correctly based on a set of instructions I followed but for some reason I'm getting: "Not Found" when I try to load in my browser `http://localhost/myservice/webservice.aspx`. Someone said that I have to configure IIS for Aspx files. I don't know how to do that. I need to know how to do that and I need help on setting up this web service?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make some assumptions... my first assumption is that since you believe this to be your problem you must be running on IIS6 with windows 2003?  Make sure you have asp.net installed.  Then Open up IIS click the + next to your server name, then click on the Web Service Extensions folder.  Then in the right side allow asp.net items.

That should do it.

Comment: I think my problem is apache

Comment: Why the heck do you try to use apache to run a .NET web service? That said, web services are NOT .aspx, but .asmx or - better - .svc (with WCF).